# State management from SPA to SPA

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, single-page-application

Is it possible to maintain state from one SPA to SPA. Let's say I have login page as one SPA and after login want to navigate to another SPA and want to manage state like user logged in information was thinking of how this could be achieved

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways of achieving that:

1. Configure the SPAs such that they are using the same store.
2. Store the state in a database, an get them when moving from one SPA to another.
3. Store the state (presumably an object) of one SPA in localStorage as a string using `JSON.stringify`. Then the second SPA would get the state of the first SPA from localStorage.